# I am trying to append two dataframes but its giving an empty dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pickle, file-format, describe

Here is the code:

```
with open('Epoch_SN001.pickle','rb') as f:
    p=pickle.load(f)
    p_des=p.describe()
    print(type(p_des))
    print(p_des)
    epoch_count=set(p.epoch)
    p_deddf=pd.DataFrame()
    p_deddf.append(p_des)
    print(p_deddf)
    print(type(p_deddf))
```

```
And here is the output: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
               time         epoch     EEG F4-M1     EEG C4-M1     EEG O2-M1  \
count  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06   
mean   1.499805e+04  4.270000e+02 -8.755249e-05 -1.536531e-04 -1.913667e-04   
std    8.660254e+03  2.468171e+02  2.037796e+01  1.805393e+01  1.607171e+01   
min    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -7.568231e+02 -6.949228e+02 -8.946693e+02   
25%    7.499000e+03  2.130000e+02 -7.433540e+00 -6.091237e+00 -5.534189e+00   
50%    1.499800e+04  4.270000e+02 -4.388772e-02  2.513637e-01  2.564227e-01   
75%    2.249700e+04  6.410000e+02  7.201991e+00  6.419278e+00  5.887075e+00   
max    2.999600e+04  8.540000e+02  8.028337e+02  7.442678e+02  7.758796e+02   

          EEG C3-M2      EMG chin     EOG E1-M2     EOG E2-M2           ECG  
count  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  6.566400e+06  
mean  -1.968810e-04  5.904567e-05 -3.301268e-05 -3.738243e-05 -8.534347e-04  
std    2.138014e+01  3.507483e+00  2.183542e+01  2.047519e+01  1.211850e+02  
min   -1.229268e+03 -1.960828e+02 -1.196565e+03 -1.181895e+03 -2.716338e+03  
25%   -6.098073e+00 -1.090589e+00 -5.947205e+00 -5.361692e+00 -3.240427e+01  
50%    6.228285e-02  3.518932e-03  1.164838e-01  8.771005e-02  1.894358e+00  
75%    6.232297e+00  1.093312e+00  6.074414e+00  5.452523e+00  3.597804e+01  
max    7.703818e+02  3.637456e+02  7.661736e+02  7.630741e+02  2.490308e+03  
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I have several other files and need to append the p.des() add to a data frame and save it in an excel file for further and future use. Any insights over this error will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> p_deddf.append(p_des)

append returns a copy of the dataFrame rather updating the dataFrame inplace.
try:
`p_deddf = p_deddf.append(p_des)`